# Migrate Delphi 2007 component to .NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, delphi, delphi-2007

I need some help.

I have generated a component in Delphi 2007 Code Gear and I need to migrate it to .NET to be used by VB.NET platform.

I generated an ActiveX dll but I have been told that only the declaration of the class is visible in .NET.

Actually the component I have generated is inherited by another component of which I have only the .dcu files. My new component is exactly similar as the parent one except from that I have overridden the constructor create.

I wonder why the .NET, although it accepted the component, it did not provide the inherited properties, methods etc.

I would appreciate any explanation, clarification, any help.

Thank you.

Comment: Not sure on the ActiveX front.   But it may require you to put the things you want visible in the published section.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of ActiveX, have you considered using Delphi prism to get your code into the .net world as a true .net assembly?